# Else Condition not working java script / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm new here, can someone please help me...
i have 2 div's #main and #side.

In my #main div i have few check boxes ,

on checked event, i apend my check box label into #side div and add/remove some classes and it's working perfectly

but when i unchecked my input,  it's not working not add/remove classes or apend to #main div

here is my code

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

    if (this.checked) {
                $(this).next('label').removeClass("icon");
                $(this).next('label').addClass("icon-active");
                $(this).next('label').detach().appendTo('#side');
    }
 else 
    {      // This condition not working //
                $(this).next('label').addClass("icon");
                $(this).next('label').removeClass("icon-active");
                $(this).next('label').appendTo('#main');
    }
});
```

Thanks in Advance

Here is a full code.
http://jsfiddle.net/o8n1b8z1/4/

Comment: you should be using $(this).is(:checked) in your if statement anbd you should investigate event delegation to allow functionality on apended / dynamically added elements to the DOM

Comment: here is full code
http://jsfiddle.net/o8n1b8z1/4/

Comment: Please place this line inside your `else` condition: `console.log('the condition is working, but your selectors do not!');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you're using `jQuery`, I suggest you do not use `this.checked`, but `$(this).is(':checked')`.

However, the reason your code is not working in reverse is because you're moving the `.next('label')` in `DOM` on checking the checkbox. So, on unchecking, `.next('label')` won't exactly return the label, as it is has been moved.

This is how I'd write your function:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
  var label = $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]'),
      checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  label.toggleClass("icon icon-active").appendTo(checked?'#side':'#main')
})
```

Now, another problem with your script is that, on return, it appends the labels to the end of the `div`, instead of after the checkboxes. To fix that, here's what you should use:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  var label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]'),
      checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  label.toggleClass("icon icon-active")[
      checked ? 'appendTo' : 'insertAfter'
  ]($(checked ? '#side' : this));
})
```

Updated your [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/o8n1b8z1/6/)

Comment: This just appends to the end of the divs. Use .after the input element

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt It appends where his script appends. I have no idea what his page looks like. Why should I make assumptions? What if I'm wrong?

Comment: Well i guessed He wants the labels to get back to the same position as how it was before he checked it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did some changes to your else statement and it works. The issue is the Label gets shifted out and the else part no longer identifies the Labels anymore.
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/o8n1b8z1/5/

```
   else 
        {      // This condition working //

    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    var label = $('label[for="' + id + '"]');
                    label.addClass("icon");

                    label.removeClass("icon-active");
                    $( "#"+id ).after(label);
        }
```